How to use switch branch button only seems to work for single repo in multi-root workspace
I am used to looking at the source control checkout button in vscode as a quick indication of what branch the IDE thinks I'm working on.
This button is in lower left of the status panel as seen here:

When I have several folders open in a multi-root workspace, each with their own repo, this button only works for one of those repos - I can't figure out how to get it to show branch options for any of the other repos.
I've done all sorts of searches like "vscode multi-root switch branch", etc. Found nothing that addresses this.
Vscode documentation only address the use of this button in the context of single root repo.
I've also right clicked the branch in the scm view and selected "make default" - which didn't help.
How does vscode determine the repo in which to display the current branch?
How can I tell vscode which of the multi-root repos to use for display and actions?

IIRC in multi-repo workspaces you have to preview or open a file from the specific workspace so the branch name in the bottom left refers to that file's project and repository. The VSCode source control view can also help managing this.
